Geometry Nodes Triangles Overlapping Faces
I'm trying to build an animation with the triangle pattern shown in the image.
I built it by using a grid node which gets triangulated twice and they are then being intersected. Afterwards the geometry is separated so that I can assign the three different colors to a third of them.
It looks okay in solid mode and Material Preview but in cycles a lot of the faces are black. I'm guessing it's because of overlapping faces but haven't found a solution for this.
Would really appreciate any help or point in the right direction




Here's a setup that produces no overlapping faces (still, it's not manifold and in particular bevel will fail):

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)
With some nodes added for coloring (see attached .blend) it becomes:

Imgur mirror

Note, the .blend is in 4.3 version, see the "Iteration" output oscket of the "Repeat" input node. The logic here is that each level should have the same extrusion height (and varying height is simply achieved by varying number of extrusions in various regions). Therefore either implement the incrementation by 1 yourself, or just base the ID/Seed on the height (since it's an integer, multiply the coordinate by a lot to have unique integers for varying levels):

Imgur mirror

Using Blender 4.2.3 to read the provided Blender 4.3 file, I end up with this result : https://i.sstatic.net/XLvmzMcg.png. It seems that the extrusion normal is not along Z axis... Any idea why ?

Sorry @StefLAncien it's 4.3 β (was supposed to be released today, but delayed). It doesn't work on 4.2 because the "Repeat Zone" doesn't have an "Iteration" value, which is a QoL feature normally implemented with an integer incremented by 1 within the zone (I'm sure you know how to do that). I'll also edit into the question another workaround for 4.2.

My bad, I missed the new Iteration socket disappearing at import in 4.2.
